# how to get response data of http listener in groovy file

Tags: groovy, mule, response, anypoint-studio, httplistener

Response is in JSON:

```
{
   "msisdn": "123",
   "starttime": "2.11",
   "endtime": "7.10",
   "type": "simple"                        
}
```

I want to access this data in groovy file for further processing, which function or method is used to access this data.

I'm using mule anypoint studio.

Comment: HTTP response is by default set to payload. you can use payload in groovy with variable `payload`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simply called "payload" in your groovy script. This simply returns the json that you receive from the HTTP Listener.

```
<flow name="test">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <scripting:component doc:name="Groovy">
        <scripting:script engine="Groovy"><![CDATA[return payload]]></scripting:script>
    </scripting:component>
</flow>
```

Here are some other examples:
https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/3.8/scripting-module-reference